# Label displays an incorrect value

Tags: objective-c

I have this code:

In .h file:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    float costBonus9;
}
```

In .m file:

```
costBonus9 = 123456789;
NSNumber *numbercost9 = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:costBonus9];
NSString *formatcost9 = [formattercost stringFromNumber:numbercost9];
Label9.text = formatcost9;
```

But Label9 displays "123456792".

What's the problem?

Comment: What's `formattercost`? Is `costBonus9` a float? Why do you append 9 to everything? Couldn't you just do `label9.text = @(costBonus9).stringValue`?

Comment: How many digits of precision do you think there *are* in a float??

Comment: What @HotLicks said; `float`s don't have enough precision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a single precision floating point number, i.e. a `float`, to represent 123456789. A float stores it's value as a combination of a significand (sometimes called the 'mantissa') and an exponent, not unlike scientific notation:

```
s * 2^e
```

The size of the significand determines how precisely you can represent a given value. A single precision float has a 24-bit significand, so you get 24 significant bits. Unfortunately, you can't fit 123456789 in 24 bits, so you get [the best approximation](http://www.binaryconvert.com/result_float.html?decimal=049050051052053054055056057) of that value that does fit, which as you've found is 123456792.

If you want an exact value, use a type that can store the value exactly. You could use a `double`, or if you'll always be storing integers you'd probably be better off with a `long int`.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a debug, and a break point to make sure that formatcost9 really has what you think it has.

To add a breakpoint in xcode, click the gray bar that seperates the Navigator (the list of classes and such) from the canvas (where the code shows), make sure you click next to the line of code you want to check. I would click at `numbercost9`, then run the program. When it reaches the breakpoint it will pause. The debug menu will be shown, click the arrow that points down towards a thick bar. This will move you through the code line by line.

There should be two boxes in the debug menu, one of the right (this is your console.) and one on the left, which shows variable values. Use this one to figure out the value of `formatcost9`.

Comment: This doesn't address the real problem, which is that the OP is trying to stuff 27 bits of information in a 24 bit bag.